# How do I find the number of interest periods per year?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I am currently self-studying logarithms and exponential equations and the book I am using includes the method of calculating different aspects of the compound interest (compounded amount, starting amount, running time, rate of interest), all other aspects being given.

But the number of interest periods per year is never the unknown in any problem, and the book doesn't deal with solving for it, all other aspects known. In short, my question would be:

> How do I find the number of interest periods per year, mathematically how do you solve for $x$ in the equation $$\left(\frac{A}{P}\right)^{(rn)^{-1}}=\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^x$$ all other letters known, or simply solve for $x$ in $$c=\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^x$$

Here is my attempt

> [image: Attempt]

- $A$ is the compounded amount
- $P$ the principal or starting amount
- $r$ the annual rate of interest
- $n$ the time of compounding in years
- $p$ the number of interest periods annually, and for example it equals $1$ if the compounding happens annually, $2$ if semi-annually, $4$ if quarterly, but this is what we are actually looking for.

Comment: Well, that's because people contemplating financial decisions in real life ask "What will my monthly payment be?", "What interest rate can I afford?", or "Should I get a 15- or 30-year mortgage?".  Nobody really thinks about the compounding frequency.  It really doesn't matter that much, since 6% compounded continuously = 6.184% compounded annually.

Comment: Welcome. Posting image is discouraged. [Images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677/963109) may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Since you are new contributor, the images have been converted to text for once (If you can't see text, assume that conversion process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self. If possible, we would like to see your efforts on question too. Happy Learning!

Comment: You are absolutely right about the insignificance of the problem in practice, and maybe therefore in theory too. The only situation I can think of is a fraud where a lot of capital is being considered and the profit comes from the small differences inceasing over time.

Comment: @RohitSingh thanks for your advice and your edit. To be honest, this is the first time I have seen the Lambert W function (I am in grade 10), but I will do my best to understand and master it.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
c &= \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x\\
\implies c^{1/x} &= 1 + \frac{1}{x}\\
\implies c^{u - 1} &= u \quad \tag{Subtitute $u = 1 + 1/x$}\\
\implies \frac{1}{u}c^{u} &= c\\
\implies \left(\frac{1}{u}c^{u}\right)^{-1} &=\frac{1}{c}\\
\implies u\cdot c^{-u} &= \frac{1}{c}\\
\implies -u\cdot c^{-u} &= \frac{-1}{c}\\
\implies -u \ln(c) \cdot e^{-u \ln(c)} &= \frac{-1}{c} \ln(c)\\
\implies -u \ln(c) &= W\left(\frac{-\ln(c)}{c}\right)\\
\implies u &= \frac{-1}{\ln(c)}W\left(\frac{-\ln(c)}{c}\right)\\
\implies 1 + \frac{1}{x} &= \frac{-1}{\ln(c)}W\left(\frac{-\ln(c)}{c}\right)\\
\implies x &= \left(\frac{-1}{\ln(c)}W\left(\frac{-\ln(c)}{c}\right) - 1\right)^{-1}\\
 &= \boxed{\frac{-\ln(c)}{W\left(\frac{-\ln(c)}{c}\right) + \ln(c)}}
\end{align}

**Note:** $W(x)$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). To compute $W(x)$ in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ProductLog%5Bx%5D), use `ProductLog[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no closed-form for this solution in terms of high-school-level mathematics.

---

Solve for $x$ in
$$
\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = c,\qquad c>1
$$
An answer in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

$$
x = \frac{-\ln(c)}{W_{-1}(-\ln(c)/c)+\ln(c)}
$$

See the link for information on the Lambert W function.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have stated, a “closed form” solution requires using [the Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  But if you don't have this function available on your calculator or programming library, you may be interested in an approximation.

Some “special” values of $c = (1 + \frac{1}{x})^x$ are:

- Annual: $x = 1 \implies c = 2$
- Semiannual: $x = 2 \implies c = 2.25$
- Quarterly: $x = 4 \implies c = 2.44140625$
- Monthly: $x = 12 \implies c \approx 2.613035290224676$
- Weekly: $x = 52.1775 \implies c \approx 2.692682824117828$
- Daily: $x = 365.2425 \implies c \approx 2.7145699419617033$
- Continuously: $x \rightarrow \infty \implies c \rightarrow e \approx 2.718281828459045$

After playing with these numbers a bit, I found a simple rational function that approximates the above values.  (Coefficients are for least-squares error on $\frac{1}{x}$.)

$$x = \frac{1}{1.14962209188153(e-c)^2 + 0.55980701470039(e-c)}$$

This gives correct (to the nearest integer) results for $1 \le x \le 6$, but works less well for more frequent compounding.